# Argument type is not assignable to parameter type and it should be

Tags: c#, generics

I have defined a class `CommandProcessor<T>` as having `T` derive from `Command` and contain a default constructor:

```
public class CommandProcessor<T> : ICommandProcessor<T> where T : Command, new()
```

The `Command` type itself also defines a default constructor and it implements an interface, `ICommand`. The interface contains a method that expects an input parameter to be of type `T`:

```
void Process(T command);
```

So I expect that I am able to define a class:

```
public class SpecificCommandProcessor : CommandProcessor<SpecificCommand>
```

it will work because `SpecificCommand` inherits from `Command` and also provides a default constructor.

All good so far.

But Visual Studio 2013 with C# 4.5 won't compile the following line:

```
CommandProcessor<Command> test = new SpecificCommandProcessor();
```

saying that it cannot convert the source type to the target type.

This means that I can also not do the following:

```
List<CommandProcessor<Command>> myList = new List<CommandProcessor<Command>>;
var toAdd = new SpecificCommandProcessor();
myList.Add(toAdd);
```

I have tried direct casting and safe casting, but none is accepted by the compiler. Yet it is obvious that `SpecificCommandProcessor` is in fact a `CommandProcessor<Command>`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try searching for "C# generics covariance".

Comment: I know what covariance is, I don't know what I'm missing to make this work.

Comment: `SpecificCommandProcessor` is *not* a `CommandProcessor<Command>`. Consider passing a `SpecificCommandProcessor` into a method accepting a parameter of type `CommandProcessor<Command>`... the API of `CommandProcessor<Command>` specifies that the passed object can process *any* command: passing a `SpecificCommandProcessor` is a violation of that constraint. Hence `CommandProcessor<T>` cannot be covariant.

Comment: Based on your comments, you use reflection to verify the types, which suggests that you take the responsibility for type compatibility from the compiler to yourself. If that's so, try a dirty hack: cast to `object` and then cast to whatever type you're assigning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the compiler happy you'd need to make `ICommandProcessor<T>` covariant in T:

```
public interface ICommandProcessor<out T> where T : ICommand
{
}
```

Now the following will compile fine:

```
ICommandProcessor<ICommand> test = new SpecificCommandProcessor(); //not the use of interfaces.

List<ICommandProcessor<ICommand>> myList = new List<ICommandProcessor<ICommand>>(); //again note the use of interfaces
var toAdd = new SpecificCommandProcessor();
myList.Add(toAdd);
```

But we haven't really solved anything because the problem will arise when you add the following (per your requirements):

```
public interface ICommandProcessor<out T> where T : ICommand //covariant in T
{
    void Foo(T t) //WILL NOT COMPILE. Contravariant in T
}
```

So basically `T` must be covariant and contravariant at the same time which is not possible; therefore `T` is invariant and that is what the compiler is telling you; if its invariant then you can not leverage any type variance "safely".

When you start running into deadends like this one, maybe you should take a step back and consider if a generic approach is really the best solution. Probably non-generic interfaces would make this a whole lot easier.

Comment: Yes, InBetween, that's the approach I'm taking right now, and I'm adding runtime checking based on reflection.

Answer (score 6):

`SpecificCommandProcessor` is NOT a  `CommandProcessor<Command>`, it's a `CommandProcessor<SpecificCommand>` - and those things are different.

Take, for example, `List<Animal>` and `List<Sheep>` (with obvious inheritance).

```
List<Animal> animals = new List<Sheep>(); // if this were legal
animals.Add(new Wolf());                  // what should this do?
```

What you can do, is leverage generic interface covariance and contravariance in C#. For example, `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, which means that this:

```
IEnumerable<Animal> animals = new List<Sheep>();
```

will actually work. That's because there is absolutely no way to add items to an IEnumerable after the fact, you can only get items from it, and the items you'll get will definitely be instances of `Animal`.
It is actually defined using `IEnumerable<out T>`, where `out` means that the result will only be used as an output from the interface, so the value is ok if it's at least a T, or any inheritor.

What you might need to do is to create a covariant interface with

```
public interface ICommandProcessor<out T> where T : Command, new(){}
```

and have the CommandProcessor implement it:

```
public class CommandProcessor<T>:ICommandProcessor<T> where T : Command, new(){}
```

In that case, the code:

```
List<ICommandProcessor<Command>> myList = new List<ICommandProcessor<Command>>();
var toAdd = new SpecificCommandProcessor();
myList.Add(toAdd);
```

compiles and works (provided that the classes are indeed keeping the covariance promise)

Comment: That is not parallel to what I'm doing. What I'm doing is creating a `List<Something<Animal>>`, then trying to add a `List<Something<Wolf>>` where `Wolf` is an `Animal`.

Comment: Same logic still applies. Will update with a specific workaround

Comment: @RoyDictus - It is the same thing because a `Something<Wolf>` is not a `Something<Animal>` due to invariance.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use `out T` in the interface declaration because I need to accept parameters of the type `T` in `ICommandProcessor<T>` (the method `Process(T command)` will be rejected if I add the `out`).

Comment: ... and even if I change that method to `void Process(Command command)` (and thus leave out the `T`), the `myList.Add(toAdd);` line still won't compile, still saying that the argument type is not assignable.

Comment: Lee, it is not the same thing. I'm not doing `Something<Wolf> xx = new Something<Sheep>()`. At all.

Comment: @RoyDictus - but it still does come down to the same thing. Just because types `T1` and `T2` have a particular inheritance relationship, that doesn't mean that `G<T1>` and `G<T2>` have the same inheritance relationship. In fact, they have no inheritance relationship.

Comment: You cannot guarantee that you won't misuse the `T` provided as a parameter to the method - so no, you might need another approach.

Comment: @RoyDictus indeed the problem is variance. If you have a List<ICommandProcessor<Command>>, you expect each element of the list to be able to process any command. If you've added a SpecificCommandProcessor, and pass it a (more generic) Command, what can it do? The types aren't compatible unfortunately, for the same reasons discussed above.

Comment: In fact, it sounds contravariant if anything. A CommandProcessor<Command> can actually do everything the method types require of a CommandProcessor<SpecialisedCommand>.

Comment: @Oly'Oil'Sourbut +1 - CommandProcessor is semantically contravariant.

Answer (score 5):

To understand the logic behind why covariance cannot work in this case, consider two "specific" command processors:

```
public class CreateCommandProcessor : CommandProcessor<CreateCommand>

public class DeleteCommandProcessor : CommandProcessor<DeleteCommand>
```

Then imagine we do this:

```
CommandProcessor<Command> processor = new CreateCommandProcessor();
```

Now, as far as the compiler is concerned, `processor` is an object that can process a command. *Any* command. So the following should be valid:

```
processor.Process(new DeleteCommand());
```

Except... it isn't valid. Because `processor` can actually only process Create commands. This is a contradiction. This is why the assignment is invalid.

More generally, this is why a generic interface taking `T` as a method parameter cannot be covariant.

It's not clear exactly how useful it is to have a list of objects that can all handle completely different inputs but if the idea is to create a command queue of sorts (or similar) consider creating something like a list of invocations instead. Something like:

```
// Note non-generic interface
public class CommandInvocation<T> : ICommandInvocation
{
    public CommandInvocation<T>(T command, CommandProcessor<T> processor)
    {
        // Assign params to fields...
    }

    public void Invoke()
    {
        _processor.Process(_command);
    }
}
```

Then you can do the following:

```
var invocations = new List<ICommandInvocation>();
invocations.Add(new CommandInvocation<CreateCommand>(createCommand,
                                                  new CreateCommandProcessor()));

invocations.Add(new CommandInvocation<DeleteCommand>(deleteCommand,
                                              new DeleteCommandProcessor()));
```

Depending on your use case, you could take this a step further and create a `CommandInvocationFactory` that injects some kind of processor resolver to give you the right processor for a given command type (so you don't have to pass the command processor explicitly each time), e.g.:

```
public ICommandInvocation Get<T>(Command<T> command)
{
    var processor = _processorFactory.Get<T>();
    return new CommandInvocation<T>(command, processor);
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
invocations.Add(_invokerFactory.Get(new CreateCommand()));
```